# insert new name for radio buttons in php loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

Within this loop I have:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = 1;
        $a = $row["a"];
        $b = $row["b"];
        $c = $row["c"];
        echo "<br>" . "<h3>Question " . $row["id"] . ": " . $row["question"] . "</h3>";
        echo "<br>A " . $a  . "<input type='radio' name='q'/><br>";
        echo     "B " . $b  . "<input type='radio' name='q'/><br>";
        echo     "C " . $c  . "<input type='radio' name='q'/><br>";
```

As radio button functionality works I will need to have a new name= every iteration of the table to ensure all buttons are not unselected.
I am thinking of just using $name and incrementing it each time but I am unsure how I could set the php variable as the name attribute in the input tag.

Any tips?

Comment: `<input type='radio' name='".$row["id"]."'/>`

Comment: love u @mplungjan

Answer (score -2):

Your idea is fine, you may use it. It would be something like this. Your variable would be $_POST["q1"], $_POST["q2"] ...

```
<?php
$name = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name++;
        $a = $row["a"];
        $b = $row["b"];
        $c = $row["c"];
        echo "<br>" . "<h3>Question " . $row["id"] . ": " . $row["question"] . "</h3>";
        echo "<br>A " . $a  . "<input type='radio' name='q".$name."'/><br>";
        echo     "B " . $b  . "<input type='radio' name='q".$name."'/><br>";
        echo     "C " . $c  . "<input type='radio' name='q".$name."'/><br>";
```